# Java Swing JFileChooser and the user.home system variable

Tags: java, swing

I'm running a Swing application using JDK 1.7.0_45 on Windows 7. It uses a JFileChooser, which it creates with the no argument constructor, which makes the starting directory my Documents folder. I'd like to change this starting directory, without changing the source code, which I don't have, by setting the user.home system variable via -Duser.home=some-dir.

There is code in sun.awt.shell.ShellFolderManager that is supposed to make that happen, and on another forum, someone claimed it did work for him, also with Java 7 and Windows 7. When I step through his source example though, I'm getting a subclass of ShellFolderManager called sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2, which works differently and doesn't look at user.home. Why would that be different for him and me given the same source code, and Windows and Java versions?

Here's the source I'm working with:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFileChooser {
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    final JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
            fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        }
    });
    button.setText("Open");
    frame.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: 32 or 64bit differences?

Comment: Yes, possibly. I have Windows 64 bit, but I'm running Java 32 bit. It's worth setting up Java 64 bit and see what happens.

Comment: Nope, it also ignores user.home when compiled and run using Java 7, 64 bit.

Comment: What about 32bit on 32bit?

Comment: I don't have a 32 bit Windows machine to test on. However, I'm going to guess that on all versions on Windows, JFileChooser really doesn't look at the user.home System variable to choose its default starting directory, and the guy who say it did is simply wrong. It's weird that the user.home behavior is overriden in the Windows implementation, but it does seem to be the case.